# use * in name class in css

Tags: css, html

What means `*` in name class of css? I think it is for inheritance class

```
<style>
.ancestors *{ 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

Comment: the asterisks are normally a Wildcard, in a lot of languages and places, they mean "anything" or "everything" normally

Comment: the selector you posted means all the descendant elements of the elements having class `ancestors` will be selected. the `*` is called the Universal selector.

Answer (score 2):

It means anything.  In this case, it applies to any element within the element with the class of `ancestors`.